# null vs empty string, different results - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Null and empty string giving me different results in my code:

```
<b-button :disabled="phone && phone.length < 9"></b-button>
```

`phone` variable is set to `null`:

```
data () {
  return {
    phone: null
}
```

in this case `phone` is equal to false, therefore my `&& phone.length < 9` statement won't fire, as i understand.

But if i set `phone: ''` (empty string), then my `phone` is set to `true` and fires the next statement `&& phone.length < 9`.

Purpose of this condition, is to disable the button, if `phone` number is empty, or has less than 9 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a computed property to easily check the input:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    phone: null,
    inputText: null
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return (this.phone ? this.phone.length < 9 : true)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="phone" />
  <br /> phone: {{ phone }}
  <br /> isDisabled: {{ isDisabled }}
</div>
```

Use the computed property directly on your button:

`<b-button :disabled="isDisabled"></b-button>`

BTW: If you're planning to do any more advanced form validation, there are easy-to-use libraries like [VeeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is not about `null` are different than empty string?

Comment: Alexander, that's not your issue. If you evaluate `Boolean("")` and `Boolean(null)`, you will notice that they both return false.

Comment: @lovrodoe, so it's my fault understanding of `phone && phone.length < 9` then? If `phone` returns `true`, only then, statement after `&&` would be fired?

Comment: That is correct. I've tested in console and it seems that both `"" && true` and `"" && false` return an empty string and don't evaluate the second statement. Having null there has a similar behaviour, it always returns null and doesn't evaluate second statement. Neither of those return true or false.

Comment: But why it does work with empty string in my case? `phone && phone.length < 9` - if it returns `false` on the first statement, then my button would never be disabled, but with empty string it is disabled (returns true). According to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators, if being used with boolean values, both of them should return `true` in order to be `true`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `:disabled` requires a `true`/`false` (IMO). However you are using short circuit evaluation that usually returns the last evaluated expression (since its an `&&` operator).

Now, can be non-boolean values. Therefore, I reckon in your expression you are actually returning a `"null"` (string) which might be valid `truthy` value for `:disabled`. In otherwords equivalent to true.

You can get what you need if you modified the expression to the following conditional.

EDITED CONDITIONAL:

```
 !(phone && phone.length && phone.length >=10).
```

Comment: I've tried double `!!phone` condition, it's the same as i posted in the beginning.

Comment: @AlexanderKim just updated the condition. This should work. Tested against `null`, `undefined`, `''` and `'abc'` (length === 3). Seems to return what you need. Let me know if it does not. Cheers.